# Windows 7 Crashes on bluetooth disconnect

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I have a set of Bluetooth headphones I use on Windows 7. Every so often, when I turn off the headphones, the entire computer crashes. I have had this happen several times, but not enough that I know the exact steps to reproduce. All I know is that I turn on my headphones, do some work, then eventually, I turn them off, and the computer crashed. I have to hard reset the computer in order for anything to happen after that.

I have installed the latest Bluetooth drivers from Intel.

Any idea what could be the problem? No anyway I can troubleshoot the problem? Is there any type of bluetooth log data of some sort that gets persisted that I could look at and see what is happening?

Comment: Anything in the event logs?

Comment: @DavidPostill Looking in Windows System events, the only event that shows up is: `The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.` Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Comment: Did you happen to ever find out a fix for this issue? Experiencing the same thing on a new Dell laptop on Windows 10.

Comment: @ach sorry, never did fix it. I am now on linux, and its working fine, go figure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a compatibility issue with the Bluetooth drivers and the operating system. As you have already updated the Bluetooth drivers, try performing a Windows update and check the status. In some cases these kind of issues will get addressed with an OS update.

Comment: I have updated windows several times since this issue started occurring.